# some of the using Directives are greyed out when using sql server

Tags: sql-server

In sql server some of the using directives are greyed out like

```
using system.collections.generic
using system.linq
using system.web``
using system.web.UI
```

Comment: Using directives are generally greyed out when there is no code using them.

Comment: Guessing "FYP" isn't really related to the question at all. If it is, please explain it in detail what it means.